# Разбиение 1 столбца на 2 столбцы (не добавлял строку в второй столбец) sqlite

Tags: sqlite

Запрос разбивает на два столбца, но если не четное количество строк в столбце который разбиваем то он копирует последнюю строку (пример вывода).

**Как сделать запрос чтобы он не копировал (добавлял) строку?**

*К примеру чтобы было пусти (null) или вообще не было.*

Запрос:

```
SELECT min(teacher_name) AS name_1, max(teacher_name) AS name_2
FROM (SELECT teacher_name, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY added_time) - 1 AS seqnum
      FROM saved_teachers WHERE user_id = ? 
     )
GROUP BY seqnum / 2
```

Пример вывод:

```
name_1  |  name_2
тест11  |  тест22
тест33  |  тест44
тест55  |  тест55 - (копия)
```

Comment: Использовать CASE.

Comment: @Akina Скажите пожалуйте как мне применить CASE в моем запросе, я не сильно разбираюсь в sqlite, спасибо

Comment: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-case/

Comment: Ну типа `... , CASE WHEN min(teacher_name) <> max(teacher_name) THEN max(teacher_name) ELSE NULL END AS name_2 ...`

Comment: @Akina  Спасибо большое. Я ети значения вставляю в клавиатуру, `NULL` заменил на `""` все супер, спасибо. Еще вопрос а если мне нужно будет разбить на 3 (три) в дальнейшем, как это сделать?

Comment: Общее решение - условная агрегация по остатку от деления. Т.е. не `min(teacher_name) AS name_1`, а `MIN(CASE WHEN seqnum MOD 2 = 0 THEN teacher_name END) AS name_1`. Тогда никакие дополнительные проверки не нужны. Соответственно тут 2 - количество столбцов, а 0 - номер столбца (для второго поля там будет 1).

Comment: @Akina Функция `MOD` ее не в sqlite я правильно понимаю, чем ее можно заменить

Comment: Это не функция, а оператор. Обычный оператор получения остатка при целочисленном делении. В SQLite - `%`.

Comment: @Akina Если нет значения в `MIN(CASE WHEN seqnum % 2 = 1 THEN teacher_name END) AS name_2` то но подставляет значение (null), python ругается на null, в первом варианте `...ELSE "" END AS name_2...` я поставил чтобы он не выдавал значение NULL, а в этом можно также сделать, Спасибо

Comment: *python ругается на null* А он-то тут при чём?

Comment: @Last_Arkhangel Я вообще-то просто имел в виду, что обработка полученного результата в питоне находится явно за пределами заданного вопроса.

Comment: @Akina Я имел введу в это выражение `... , CASE WHEN min(teacher_name) <> max(teacher_name) THEN max(teacher_name) ELSE NULL END AS name_2 ...` вместо `NULL` можно задать другое значение (к примеру "тест"), а с этим выражением `MIN(CASE WHEN seqnum % 2 = 1 THEN teacher_name END) AS name_2` можно также или нет?

Comment: При отсутствии секции ELSE и невыполнении условие значение выражения будет NULL. Ну а при наличии - что напишешь. то и получишь. Так что просто добавь в CASE секцию ELSE с нужным тебе значением. Например, `MIN(CASE WHEN seqnum % 2 = 1 THEN teacher_name ELSE '' END) AS name_2`.

Comment: @Akina Тут нюанс в том что выражение `MIN(CASE WHEN seqnum % 2 = 1 THEN teacher_name ELSE '' END) AS name_2` присваивает всем строкам (данного столбца) одинаковое значение не последней строке (которой нет вообще)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT teacher_name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY added_time) - 1 rn
    FROM saved_teachers 
    WHERE user_id = ? 
)
SELECT MIN(CASE WHEN rn % N = 0 THEN teacher_name END) column_1,
       MIN(CASE WHEN rn % N = 1 THEN teacher_name END) column_2,
-- ...
       MIN(CASE WHEN rn % N = N-1 THEN teacher_name END) column_N
FROM cte
GROUP BY rn / N;
```

[modelling fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=74cb41c133806f35d54e661071edc2f6)